# No PSN+ Membership benefits?

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

So the master ( Primary ) account has a Playstation Plus membership with 11 months left to go before expiration.

Why isn't my local profile on the same Playstation 4 system getting any multiplayer benefits if no settings have been changed? I've been playing for 2 weeks and suddenly it doesn't work.

Any help would be lovely.

Comment: By "multiplayer benefits" I'm assuming you mean you can't play online games?

Comment: Do you mean primary account as the main account used, or first account used? Or has the console actually been set as the primary console for that account?

Answer (score 1):

For any secondary (i.e. non PS+) accounts to benefit, the PS+ account must of set this system as the primary system.

This is achieved via the instructions on the [playstation site](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjQkcPOrNTJAhXEuBQKHb-gC0cQFggfMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmanuals.playstation.net%2Fdocument%2Fgb%2Fps4%2Fsettings%2Factivation.html&usg=AFQjCNHxSyEKSgMQZE_Uo0cgxyYbA33edQ)